# Joomla: Plugins for a plugin - how to 'advertise' capabilities?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am working on a plugin which will have its own plugins to handle various events.

Now I'm thinking of enabling this plugins to add their own "commands". But I wonder how to treat that most efficiently. I have a list of my own commands which I search in the article anyway. Should I then just trigger a `DoWhatYouWant($article)`-event - or, since I do the searching (and parsing of params) anyway, perhaps I could build a global command-list and then trigger an "`ExecuteCommand($article,$cmd,$params)`"-event? Sounds nicer, but then (I think) I'd have to build this command-list (so that my program know what to look for), so every plugin would have to somehow 'advertise' what it could do, i.e. the names of commands it could handle - and I have no idea how that could be done.

Or is there a better (more standardized?) approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import your plugins trough the plugin helper

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('mycmdplugins');
```

then you can get all available commands which are supported by your sub plugins like

```
$cmds = JDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger('onMyAwesomeCmds');
```

With the $cmds variable you know now which commands are supported by the sub plugins and you can parse the article for them. Then you can do

```
foreach ($cmds as $cmd) {
  preg_match_all("{".$cmd."*}", $article->text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  if (!empty($matches)) {
    JDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger('onMyAwesome'.ucfirst($cmd), array($article, $params));
  }
}
```

To eliminate more repeating tasks I suggest that the additional plugins will extend a base class from your plugins folder.

Comment: This handles plugins that deal with a known set of commands. But my main concern is to enable a plugin to add his own commands - should my plugin care about that at all (to eliminate repeating tasks) or just leave it to the other plugins (with the `DoWhatYouWant`-approach)...?

Comment: I've updated the code how to call the function dynamically. Now a another plugin can implement onMyAwesomeEdit for the edit command? With this approach the main plugin doesn't need to know if a plugin is available for this command.

Comment: Sorry - maybe my english is too bad to explain this correctly, or maybe I was making too many assumptions. I've added an example which hopefully helps to make it clearer. The dynamic code does not help much, I think - because my plugin does not even know that $cmd is a command - unless it tries to interpret every {text} that it finds - which is taking too much time, I think - so I'm looking for a better design which would enable the program to look at "real candidates" only...

Comment: Updated my answer to get first a list of commands and then run it on them only.

Comment: Thank you - I'll do it that way, I like this approach. Unfortunately triggering "getCommandList" on the plugins returns an empty array - but I'll put that into another post :)

Comment: Story continues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134102/why-is-my-plugin-not-triggered)

Comment: Thanks very much - @Laoneo - I finished the project now and the plugin is available on http://contentbymail.de - I'm curious how ppl will respond to the possibility of having their own plugins :)